# A User Agent that says just "Mozilla/4.0" is a bot, right?

Tags: security, user-agent, bots

I'm getting several requests in web apps that are basically wrong in ways my code shouldn't be generating...
Mainly it's requests to .ashx without any GET parameters specified.

The user agent is "Mozilla/4.0" (nothing more than that)
The IPs vary from day to day.

This is a bot, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems very odd to me.  Any legitimate bot would identify itself in a way you can recognize.  Any malicious bot would be able to do a much better job making the user agent look like a normal browser.  This is somewhere in the middle.  That, combined with the bad requests, leads me to believe you're dealing with plain old incompetence.

Either way, you probably want to 404 these requests rather than return a yellow screen error.

Comment: I'm showing the default error page I created, which just says "unexpected error", is a bit more friendly to humans than the YSoD, and also hides the error details from malicious people.
I think that should be returning a 500 too, so the bot *should* get a hint...
But I agree with your incompetence theory completely.

Comment: You 404 so that a bot doesn't think there's a real page there.  Otherwise, a malicious bot might try something else on the page later, and this time they might get lucky.  And a search engine will keep coming around now and then to re-index.  If you 404 the blank page, the bot will just go away.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to bump old question, but I think this is the bot used by the Great Firewall of China.
They crawl web contents, and do their censorship.

Check your log and see if there is anything like 'GET /cert/bazs.cert'.

100% sure if this is found.

Comment: I didn't find a request for bazs.cert in the log, but I think your answer is the correct one, because I got a request with this User-Agent just after I sent a link to someone in China.

Comment: @michau If the link appears in QQ(IM software, popular in China), or you browse your site with Tencent Traveller(TT browser?), the bot would show up immediately. Tencent has its own search engine, User-Agent is like '... Sosospider ...', not just 'Mozilla/4.0'

Comment: Sorry to add to this so many years afterwards. The "Great Firewall of China" explanation is what we found was most correct. We traced all the clientip addresses using the `Mozilla/4.0` useragent string back to "China Telecom Shanghai".

Comment: We noticed this kind of logs recently, after some research we think they're just some crawlers from Mainland China, because we shared some of our links via Wechat :). BTW, logs like 'GET /cert/bazs.cert' means Mainland China government is trying to fetch your Records registered to the goverment of your website.

Comment: We are pretty sure it's Wechat. We use wechat sdk to share links, every time we share a link via wechat sdk, there will be two new logs with agent **Mozilla/4.0**.

Comment: @JohnnyZhao Not just Wechat, but all products of Tencent. QQ, its browser, etc.

Answer (score 5):

According to http://www.user-agents.org the 'Yahoo Mindset: Intent-driven Search' bot reports this.

But yeah it wouldn't be a browser reporting that.

Answer (score 1):

Are these requests to existing pages you wrote yourself, or do they get a 404?

In the latter case, it could be some sort of scan attack, trying to detect vulnerable application instances before hitting them with an exploit.

Comment: Nope, they are files I wrote myself (or at least, they exist, like WebResource.axd)
The script obviously found them by checking the HTML of other pages.
I'm getting error reports because the script is GETting them without parameters (which these files expect)

Answer (score 1):

I had implemented asp.net side request tracking on several web sites and by looking at records I can say that only User agent "Mozilla/4.0" can be produced by any of this reasons:

- incompetence
- search robots
- attack bots

It's interesting that my first Android was identified as "Safari 3.0", the latest Android is identified as "Mozilla 0"! So it's hard to point incompetence to specific software generation.

Returning 404 on every such request maybe would not be the best approach for Search robots, especialy if this is public web site with frequent content change.

On the other hand you should be aware that requests to `WebResource.axd` where destination is invalid are pointing to cross site scripting attacks. In this situations using SanitizerProvider is recommended. You can read more about this type of attack on [Cross-site_scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Another good thing to identify attacks is looking at IIS log files, that are commonly positioned on [system root]:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1. Here is snipp from my tool for parsing IIS log files:

[image]

In this cases User agent was not a problem, bot attack was identified by requesting "/dbadmin/index.php" from 2 different IPs. There are couple of files/pages that attack bots are looking for.

Hope this helps and gives additional value to this question.